# What's wrong with my Verilog code

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

This is my first Verilog code, and it doesn't give a result. I would like to know what's wrong with it. Thank you
This is my code:

design:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module 2Assignment(input A0, A1, B0, B1, output O0, O1, O2);

  assign #3 O0 = A0^B0;

  assign #8 O1 = (B1&~A1&~A0) | (B1&~B0&~A1) | (A1&~B1&~B0) | (A1&~A0&~B1) | (A0&B0&~A1&~B1) | (A1&A0&B1&B0);

  assign #5 O2 = (A1&B1) | (A1&A0&B0) | (A0&B1&b0);

endmodule
```

testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module Test_2Assignment;
  reg A0, A1, B0, B1;
  wire O0, O1, O2;
  
  2Assignment AS (A0, A1, B0, B1, O0, O1, O2);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("Test_2Assignment.vcd");

    $dumpvars(1, AS);
    A0=0; A1=0; B0=0; B1=0;
    #20 B0=1;
    #20 A1=1; B0=0;
    #20 A1=0; A0=1; B0=1;
    #20 B1=1;
    #20 A1=1; B1=0;
    #20 A0=0; B1=1;
    #20 A0=1;
    #20 $finish;
  endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: We don't know what you are trying to do, expected results, actual results.

Comment: @mhnrt i rolled it back for you ... by the way `it doesn't give a result` is a useless description if a problem ... it does not say what it actually does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog module names must not begin with a number.  Change:

```
2Assignment
```

to something like:

```
Assignment2
```

Make this change to both files.

The same applies to other Verilog identifiers, such as signal names.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.6 *Identifiers, keywords, and system names*:

> The first character of a simple identifier shall not be a digit or $ ;
> it can be a letter or an underscore.  Identifiers shall be case sensitive.

You must also change `b0` to `B0`, since signal names are case-sensitive (as above).